# Can you do syntax highlight for Firebase security rules in a markdown file?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, markdown, firebase-security

This is a very superficial question, but I'd like to get some docs I'm working on as clean as possible. Is there a way to highlight Firebase security rule syntax in a markdown file? What I'm looking for is something like this:

````
```firebase-security-rules
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
    }
}
```
````

I've found examples such as [this repo](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/how-to-firebase/full-stack-firebase/master/cloud-firestore/security-rules.md) (they specify `text` after the backticks) and [this repo](https://github.com/alexpaul/Firebase-Security-Rules/blob/master/README.md) (they specify `javascript` after the backticks). I've also found [a plug-in to do syntax highlights for security rules in the IntelliJ IDE](https://github.com/anboralabs/intellij-firebase-highlighter), but this is not what I'm looking for either.

I only want to know if there is a way to add specific color highlighting for the Firebase security rule language.

*PS: not sure if this is the right community to ask this, if you have any objections let me know.*

Comment: Markdown is just a text file format. Highlighting the syntax of source code example in markdown only becomes possible when you open the file in a tool (like IntelliJ in your explanation, or Stack Overflow itself here). Which tool do you want to enable syntax highlighting for your code blocks in?

Comment: GitHub and Confluence.